# Not able to run builds on travis after using SPM plugin

Tags: swift, travis-ci, swift-package-manager, swiftgen

Getting following error when running builds having any SPM plugin like [SwiftGenPlugin](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGenPlugin):

```
The following build commands failed:
    Validate plug-in “SwiftGenPlugin” in package “swiftgenplugin”
```

Build link: https://app.travis-ci.com/github/mukesh-mt/SwiftGenTest/jobs/592013507

Sample project: https://github.com/mukesh-mt/SwiftGenTest

Comment: The same appears in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: @SHato use `-skipPackagePluginValidation` option in xcodebuild command to skip package validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using `-skipPackagePluginValidation` option in `xcodebuild`.

With fastlane you can pass it with `--xcargs "-skipPackagePluginValidation"` option in gym command

See this build https://app.travis-ci.com/github/mukesh-mt/SwiftGenTest/builds/259435024

Comment: I use Bitrise, before executing Fastlane step, I invoke a script described here (https://forums.swift.org/t/telling-xcode-14-beta-4-to-trust-build-tool-plugins-programatically/59305/7)